# Method Not Allowed: /blog/tag/django

Tags: python, django

Сайт работает, но при попытке вывести tag_detail и post_detail выдаёт

> Method Not Allowed

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from django.views.generic import View
    from .models import Post, Tag
    from .utils import ObjectDetailMixin

    def posts_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})


    class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Post
        template = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    #   def get(self, request, slug):
    #       post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug__iexact=slug)
    #       return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context={'post': post})


    class TagDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Tag
        template = 'blog/tag_detail.html'
    #   def get(self, request, slug):
    #       tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug__iexact=slug)
    #       return render(request, 'blog/tag_detail.html', context={'tag': tag})

    def tags_list(request):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})
```

utils.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from .models import *

    class ObjectDetailMixin:
        model = None
        template = None

    def get(self, request, slug):
            obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
            return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})
```

urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),
        path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),
        path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url'),
        path('tag/<str:slug>', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url')
    ]
```

models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.shortcuts import reverse

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
        body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)


    class Tag(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

Comment: Полный стек-трейс пожалуйста

Comment: Просто замените `(ObjectDetailMixin, View)` на `(DetailView)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было поставить tab в utils.py на 9, 10, 11 строке.